# SwiftUI if condition in ZStack

Tags: swift, if-statement, swiftui, conditional-statements, zstack

I have a simple view in SwiftUI. There's a variable called connectionState. It's set to true for testing.

```
@State var connectionState: Bool = true

@ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            if self.connectionState {
                ConnectionStatusBar()
                    .padding(.bottom, -24.0)
                    .offset(x: 0.0, y: -75.0)
            }
        }
    }
```

But the View is never shown. When I delete the condition it is shown as it should. Is it impossible to use if condition in ZStack?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you are stating. Your code works perfectly fine and ConnectionStatusBar View is shown as expected. I am using Xcode Version 11.5.

Comment: To answer your question, if conditions can be used in ZStack and it will work.

Comment: I found the mistake. When I add a Padding of -24 the height is <= 0. When I add frame height the view is shown.